# when the player intersects the obstacle the life should only decrease by 1 but it is too much decrease

Tags: xna

following image is showing the  negative life of the player.... because  intersecting   with obstacles in the way...i want the solution for only decreasing life by one point after intersecting.

```
        if (Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.mirchirect) || Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.crabrect) || Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.stonerect) || Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.cactusrect))
        {
            die = true;
           currentframe = 19;

        }
        else { die = false; }


        if (die)
        {
          life -= 1;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I decrement lives on collision, using XNA with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509167/how-can-i-decrement-lives-on-collision-using-xna-with-c)

Comment: @DavorMlinaric thnx dude

Comment: @DavorMlinaric that bool logic is not working in my code ....wyh??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible way... add one bollean variable `PlayerHitted` to your obstacles, and when collision happened set `life -= 1` if `PlayerHitted` is false (by default) and update `PlayerHitted` to true.

that way obstacles will have information if they hit player

Comment: by using your code only once the life is decreased by 1..it does not decreasing th3 life again

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because the code is updating 60 frames per second and `die == true`, then the life of your object would decrease by 60 each second, instead of 1.

Comment: its decreasing by 27 to 3o

Answer (score 0):

```
          if (Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.mirchirect) || Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.crabrect) || Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.stonerect) || Texture.playerrect.Intersects(Texture.cactusrect))
        {
            die = true;
            currentframe = 19;
            if (!Update)
            {
                life--;
                Update = true;
            }


        }
        else { die = false; Update = false; }
```